# How to get cargo-expand to expand macros within macros

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm learning Rust and am trying to use cargo-expand on the default Hello, World program. From what I understand it's supposed to expand all the macros, but when I use it, it leaves in a macro that another macro generates.

```
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::rust_2021::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
fn main() {
    {
        ::std::io::_print(format_args!("Hello, World\n"));
    };
}
```

From what I understood, the output of `cargo expand` should expand everything, so I'm a little confused. I tried googling and searching for an answer but everything I read showed no macros within the output.

Is this right or not?

Comment: Please, do not include code as screenshots but as text. If you wonder why, google it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the `format_args!`, I'll quote dtolnay (the cargo-expand maintainer) from [this issue](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand/issues/173):

> This is working correctly. `format_args` does not expand to Rust code. (In the past it used to.)

Cargo-expand *does* recursively expand macros. Just in this case it can't.

Comment: This is because `format_args!()` is builtin in the AST today.